# Show that if $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ is not a prime, then it is a strong pseudoprime to the base 2.

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$
is not a prime, then it is a strong
pseudoprime to the base 2.

Note that this is not a homework. I find this funny exercise on my text book and willing to know the way to proof it.

Comment: What do u mean by "strong" pseudoprime?

Comment: First write out the definition of a [strong pseudoprime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongPseudoprime.html) to the base $2$, and it isn't too hard from there to check that any composite $F_n$ does indeed satisfy the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $n>1$. Write $F_n = 1 + d 2^s, d=1.$ Then $F_n$ is a strong pseudoprime base 2 if either $2^d = 2 \equiv 1 \bmod F_n$  or there is an $r$ with $0 \le r < s-1$ and $2^{2^r} \equiv -1 \bmod F_n$.

The first condition is false if $n>1$, but the second is always true: We have $s=2^n > n+1$ and you can just take $r=n < s-1$ and compute
$$2^{2^r} = 2^{2^n}=F_n-1 \equiv -1 \bmod F_n$$